# Request Returns Response 447

Tags: python-3.x, http, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to scrape a website using requests and BeautifulSoup. When i run the code to obtain the tags of the webbpage the soup object is blank. I printed out the request object to see whether the request was successful, and it was not. The printed result shows response 447. I cant find what 447 means as a HTTP Status Code. Does anyone know how I can successfully connect and scrape the site?

Code:

```
r = requests.get('https://foobar)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text())

Output:
''
```

When I print request object:

```
print(r)

Output:
<Response [447]>
```

Comment: I would search the particular website to see if there's documentation somewhere that lists their response codes. Also it's tough to try to answer your question as how to successfully scrape a site which you have not provided (what's the site?) All anyone can do is answer how you'd generally do it, which your code should in normal circumstances work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely your activity is acknowledged by the site so it's blocking your access,you can fix this problem by including  headers in your request to site.

```
import bs4
import requests
session=requests.session()
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0","Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"}
req=session.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text)
```

Comment: [timmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10294519/timmy) your solution worked like a charm. Can you further explain how headers allow someone to by pass the block?

Comment: whenever you open a site using python or normal browsing  ,certain headers are sent to the site ,the most common headers are "User -Agent","connection" and "Accept" ,when you open the site using python to get the page source your User-Agent is "Python-urllib/3.4"  (or what ever version of `urllib` you have) ,this makes it easy for the site to detect bots or spiders hence ban them or ban their IP address. While when you open site in normal browsing your User-Agent is more human-like such as Mozilla or Chrome or whatever ,requests library allows you to change you headers

Comment: [timmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10294519/timmy) Makes sense. I will include headers in future scraping. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like they have browser detection software and they don't like your browser. (meaning they don't like your lack of a browser)

While 447 is not a standard error status for http, it is occasionally used in smtp as too many requests.

Without knowing what particular website you are looking at, it's not likely anyone will be able to give you more information. Chances are you just need to add headers.