# Requests / BeautifulSoup VS robots.txt

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, python-requests

Im trying to scrape a certain website, with a single input.
right now i have built it with Scrapy, and its working great, after all of the tweaks (including not obeying robots.txt), and its running on a loop automatically to data mine.

now i need to make something that will scrape a single page by input

problem is, the only page im able to access is the robots.txt page, and im not able to find any info online about going around robots.txt.

is there any tutorial on how to do it with BS or Requests?

Comment: robots.txt is not a protected page (as it's purpose is to be crawled by bots). Can you share the URL ?

Comment: any crunchbase company page.

Comment: You want to scrape the robots.txt file, right?

Comment: No, the robots.txt file is the only one im able to connect to, any other page returns 403, and robots.txt is the only one that returns me 200, even the login page.

Im new to Requests and BS, so maybe im missing something, maybe i'll need to change the UA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing these headers, and you will get the expected output.

```py
import requests

headers = { 'accept':'*/*',
'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language':'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7,la;q=0.6',
'cache-control':'no-cache',
'dnt':'1',
'pragma':'no-cache',
'referer':'https',
'sec-fetch-mode':'no-cors',
'sec-fetch-site':'cross-site',
'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
 }

URL = "https://www.crunchbase.com/login"

response = requests.get(url=URL, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! it does! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did upvote, but it won't be seen publicly due to me being under 15 reputation, but thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

`requests` is module you use to actually get the HTML,
`beautifulsoup` is the parser you use to move through the HTML(allows you to choose the elements you want), and the answer to your question requests doesn't actually care about the robots.txt file (weather allowed or not allowed),if your requests are getting blocked I suggest [request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983250/request-returns-response-447/53991381#53991381).

scrapy on the other hand actually reads and understands the robots.txt and you will have to set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False` in order to scrape a "not-allowed" page.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, will view the headers, used request only for unprotected websites until now, maybe that's the problem.